# Are these Manifolds or not? (2 Questions)

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

> 1) Consider the ellipse E defined by $\ f(x,y)=0 $ where
>   $$
> \begin{equation}
>   f(x,y)= x^2 + 4y^2-4
> \end{equation} 
> $$
>    Show that E is a manifold by giving explicit cooridinates patches $\alpha_i$: $\ U_i\to\ V_i$.
>
> 2)Let the map $\alpha :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^2} $  be given by the equation 
>   \begin{equation}
>   \alpha(t) = (t^2+3, t^3+2)
> \end{equation} and let M be the image set. Argue whether M is an manifold or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\alpha_1:(0,2\pi)\rightarrow E$ defined by $\alpha_1(t)=(2\cos t,\sin t)$, and $\alpha_2:(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\rightarrow E$ defined by $\alpha_2(t)=(2\cos t,\sin t)$ is an atlas of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Hint** : there are easy parametrization of you ellipse using trigonometric functions or square roots.

2) **Hint** : By translation this is the same as the set $(t^2,t^3)$ which is well know to be non-smooth with a singular point given by a "cusp". You can argue that the geometric tangent space (i.e the set of vectors which arise as derivative of path along $M$) is not a vector space (it's a half-line) so your point is non smooth.